# How to draw or create a rounded rectangle in Blender using curves (not a plane/cube)?

Tags: bezier-curves, svg

I am interested in creating rounded rectangles from curves (not planes or cubes). I am aware of how to round a plane's corners using the bevel modifier.

The best I have done for rounded rectangles using curves is to make an SVG of a rounded rectangle from illustrator and import it to a curve.

This looks like:

[image]

[image]

You can see the curve features two nodes on each edge with handles all running along the horizontal and vertical axes.

Is there some way to draw or create something like that directly in Blender easily or modify the degree of rounding?

Otherwise I will just keep making them in Illustrator and importing them like this when such a shape curve is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Blender has the same tools as Illustrator, if you enable two addons:

- Add Curve: Extra Objects (to add a rectangle)
- Add Curve: Curve Tools (to round corners)

[image]

Comment: wow...didn't know that. Learning everyday here...!!! +1

Comment: me too. i just tried the shipped adddons and it worked :))

Comment: Very cool. Thanks. Only downside is you can't use the same function to edit the corner roundness once it's made. Looks like you only get one chance to determine the roundness unless I'm missing something but thanks. it's still great and I'm using this method now. Still faster than making it in Illustrator and exporting. Please let me know if I missed something in terms of how to change the roundness once they are made. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @mike :). I don't know more than you, only discovered the plugin when answering this question :)). Anyways, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 9):

Geometry Nodes lets you construct this curve as a modifier on a dummy object:

[image]

which means it can be adjusted after creation:

[image]

However the disadvantage is that constructive modifiers can't be applied on curves without first converting them to a mesh. If you need to manipulate the curve as a Bezier in Edit Mode , something like [@Jachym's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250682/35559) is better.

Comment: damn...that's right!!! +1

Comment: @Chris .. nothing wrong with your answer.. many ways to skin this cat. I think Jachym's is closest.

Comment: I think so too. Less work 

Answer (score 3):

Create a plane, TAB, CTRL-SHIFT-B -> move your mouse as you desire it, then object -> convert to curve

[image]